# Python Recursion Handling

Tags: python, recursion

I have to recursively traverse some objects inside a list.

```
def function():
   for object in list:
      if object.field is None:
         // stuff here
      else: 
          function(object.field)
   return something
```

The problem that I'm facing is that python doesn't do it for all the object inside the list, but instead it return what he get every time he meet with an " object.field != None " . 
All i want to do is return only when the for loop is over, until all the object inside my list are done.

Can someone explain me a way to do this?

Comment: Does `stuff here` include a `return` statement? If so, are you sure you understand what `return` does? Because when a function call hits `return`, that's it. It's over. Execution immediately continues from where the function was called.

Comment: Im not calling a return in stuff here.

Comment: We're going to need to see [code we can actually run, that actually reproduces the problem when we run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is especially the case since you changed `!=` to `=`, which rather dramatically changes how the code should be interpreted and makes the syntax problems even worse than they were before.

Comment: I will put a little piece of code as example in the next hours.

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling the function again when `object.field` is `None`. The first block of the `if` will be run when `object.field != None`. The `else` will be run when `object.field == None`.